# RaphaelJS rotation not working

Tags: javascript, raphael, rotation

I'm banging my head against a wall with this one. I have raphael js version 2.0 and I need to make images rotate in a way that's cross-browser. I would love to do it in CSS3, but not all browsers support what I need to do.

so, after racking my brain, I went to the Raphael playground and tried out some code in there. Doesn't work there either. What's going on here?

go to playground: http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html
run this code, should see an outline of a square.
paper.rect(100, 100, 300,300).animate({rotation:"-45"}, 2000);

using transform works:

paper.rect(100, 100, 300,300).animate({transform:"r45"}, 2000);

but unfortunately with transform, I can't seem to specify a centerpoint. I want the object to rotate off the bottom-left corner. I can do that with this code:

paper.rect(100, 100, 300,300).rotate(45,0,300)

but that doesn't animate, or accept easing, or have any callbacks.

I've seen "rotation" in several examples including these:

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php#PAGETOP
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

thanks,
- keith

Comment: This one is still working: http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation attribute seems to be missing from the 2.0 specification. It existed in 1.x. I don't know why this is so, but I can't find it in the new documentation. I expect this is an oversight that will be corrected in a minor revision going forward.

In the meantime, you can create your own animation handler and call .rotate on each tick based on your own easing.

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling something was missing. Turns out the effect was removed from the specs. I feel like this was a good learning experience and I thank everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 12):

Going to the [playground site](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/playground.html) and pasting this code:

```
paper.rect(100, 100, 300,300).animate({transform:"r-45,0,0"}, 2000);
```

rotates the rectangle from the absolute 0,0 position. See raphael js code @ [github](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.core.js#L1763-1776), which shows that `transform` can either take 2 or 4 parameters for to achieve a rotation.