# rotation not being recognized as an attr() property

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using Raphael. Here is the code for a tetris block that I want to rotate with an animation:

```
function ele(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var paper = new Raphael(ele('canvas_container'), 500, 500);

        var tetronimo = paper.path('M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z')
        tetronimo.attr({
            gradient: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',
            stroke: '#3b4449',
            'stroke-width':10,
            'stroke-linejoin':'round',
            rotation:-90, //**This is where the problem is**
            title:'This is a tetris block'
        });

        tetronimo.animate({
            rotation:360 //**This is where the problem is**
        }, 2000, 'bounce');
    }
```

This code can also be found in this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

There is no event other than `onload` that triggers the animation, but when the page loads no animation is executed. I have also tried using Raphael's transform method:

```
tetronimo.attr({
            gradient: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',
            stroke: '#3b4449',
            'stroke-width':10,
            'stroke-linejoin':'round',
            transform:'r90',
            title:'This is a tetris block'
        });
tetronimo.animate({
            transform:'r360'
        }, 2000, 'bounce');
```

But this also does not work. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908853/848090), rotation was removed with Raphael 2.0.

I tried your `transform` example on the [Raphael playground page](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html) and it worked for me